# webpack vendor module root reference-able as "vendor"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have the following setup:

```
app/src
app/vendors/
app/vendors/foo
app/vendors/foo/src
```

I set an env variable like `APP_VENDOR=foo` and would like webpack 1.x to have `./src` and `"./" + process.env.APP_VENDOR" + /src` as the resolver roots in a way that I can reference files from the vendor directory in my JS files as `vendor/file` and it would import `app/vendors/foo/src/file.js`

Is that possible with webpack 1.x?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resolve/alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#aliasing).

In your webpack config file do something like that:

```
...
resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname),
    alias: {
        vendor1: "src/vendor",
        vendor2: path.join(__dirname, process.env.APP_VENDOR + "/src")
    }
}
...
```

Then in the modules just import using `alias` definition:

```
import MyVendor from "vendor1/MyVendor.js"; //it will lookup into ./src/vendor/MyVendor.js
```

Comment: This does not work. Webpack includes the vendorX code in `eval` statements that also include the sourcemap somehow.